# Does repository in sources.list contain the same versions of packages as the most recent Debian DVD?

Tags: debian

Does the line

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
```

in `sources.list` correspond to Debian 10.0 or 10.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
```

points at a mirror of the main Buster repository, which always contains the latest point release of the corresponding version of Debian: Buster is Debian 10, so this will always give you the latest 10.*x* (10.1 currently). This is what is shipped in the downloadable images (CD, DVD, Blu-ray).

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
```

and

```
deb http://security.debian.org buster/updates
```

contain packages which are newer than the latest point release; they will be folded into the next point release when it’s prepared.

Comment: I'm confused: `buster-updates` contains 10.1, but `buster` + `security` is newer than 10.1. "updates" should be newer than 10.1 ...

Comment: I'm installing from most recent DVD (10.1) and need to install some more packages afterwards. Which repository do I need to add? I don't want updates - I want the same versions of packages as if I installed everything by downloading all DVDs for this release (10.1).

Comment: Sorry, I got the updates part mixed up (I was editing too quickly). To install the packages you’d get from the DVD, you need `buster`.